Use a mosaic image of aerial imagery with the classification wizard in ArcGIS Pro
I've been trying to run the classification wizard tools in ArcGIS Pro with a mosaic of 4 aerial multiband images. I have all the licenses to do so and the mosaic image is multiband.
I'm able to run a unsupervised classification but the classification wizard and classification tools are greyed out. I'm thinking it has something to do with the mosaic.
I am on ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2.

On 3.2 I can confirm that that classification wizard is available to both a single TIF orthomosaic generated from multiple drone images.  It is also available in a 4 band file geodatabase mosaic dataset.  Can you be more clear on the file type?

It is a .tif file.

I also exported the existing mosaic into a smaller picture using the export raster function

Hmm, you mention that you have the licenses (3d analyst or spatial analyst).  Can you confirm that?   Go to project - licensing.  Confirm that 3d or SA extensions are actually licensed?  Also, use gdalinfo or EXIFTool to extract metadata from your file.  Included that returned information to your post.
